# Adding image to initrd image

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, lenovo, acpi

I am new to Ubuntu and tried to get Ubuntu 20.04 to run on my lenovo yoga 7i.

The sound does not work when you start.

I found [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Yoga_(Gen_3)#Manual_method) tutorial on ArchWiki. The issue I am running into is trying to add /boot/acpi_override to the initrd path so when I run sudo update-grub I go from:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-34-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic
```

To:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/acpi_override /initrd.img-5.11.0-34-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/acpi_override /initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic
```

The tutorial states to change the configuration file usually located in /boot/grub/grub.cfg but when you go to grub.cfg there is a comment stating:

```
DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE 
It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
```

When I did edit the initrd line in grub.cfg, the kernel panicked and would not allow me to boot, but there is a chance I edited the wrong line

Does anyone know what file/line to change to add acpi_override to initrd on Ubuntu 20.04?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the documentation from Archlinux is incorrect. In step 8 you are instructed to add the following code to etc/default/grub:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="mem_sleep_default=deep"
 GRUB_EARLY_INITRD_LINUX_CUSTOM="/boot/acpi_override"
```

What this line of code should really read is

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="mem_sleep_default=deep"
 GRUB_EARLY_INITRD_LINUX_CUSTOM="acpi_override"
```